# How to stream Youtube audio from a Windows machine to a DLNA client?

Tags: windows-10, youtube, audio-streaming, dlna

I.e., just the audio. I have an ONKYO receiver that only supports audio streaming over DLNA, no video.

Answer (score 4):

You can stream every kind of PC audio to a DLNA receiver with [Stream What You Hear](http://www.streamwhatyouhear.com/).

> Stream What You Hear (SWYH) is a Windows application to broadcast the sound of your computer (ie: “what you hear”) on an UPnP/DLNA device such as TVs, amps, network receivers, game consoles, etc...

[image]

Comment: This solution is hardly ideal, as it streams all your machine's audio. Also, the lag between when the audio was "played" on the machine and when it actually reaches the DLNA receiver can be quite annoying.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is now built-in to Microsofts Edge browser. Microsoft calls it "cast media to device" and it is "the new version of Play To".

http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/28189-microsoft-edge-cast-media-device-windows-10-a.html

In short, load the Youtube video or other media in an Edge tab, click the three-dots-button, then choose "cast media to device" and choose a connected device.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: @Falco: Yes, but there's currently a bug in Edge that will cause high volume level spikes on the target device when Youtube's Autoplay kicks in. For viewing a single video though, it works just fine!

Comment: for me it does not work at all or amazon fire tv stick is not the right pairing device....

Comment: @Falco: From what I can tell, the Amazon Fire tv stick does not support DLNA out of the box.

Comment: why do you think, it is DLNA that the device needs to support? My TV does it natively but no Edge.

Comment: @Falco: Well, Microsoft says the target device requires DLNA or it should be a Miracast device: https://blogs.windows.com/windowsexperience/2015/10/29/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-10576/ (From what I can tell, Miracast also uses DLNA, but there you go.)

Comment: I also have a Panasonic DLNA certified TV but nothing my Win10 computer or Edge finds....which would be not unusual as it acts as a client and searches a server

Comment: @Falco: if you search for Devices in Windows 8+, it should find DLNA clients on the same network.

Comment: it "should" ;) It finds my fireTv but trying to connect does not really work.

Comment: This functionality was removed from Edge in Creator's Update (i.e. it's no longer possible to cast from Edge to a DLNA device).

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across this discussion, years later. For anyone else who comes via a search: **as of March 2021 it is possible to cast to a DLNA-supporting device from Windows 10**, with Microsoft Edge and with the Film & TV app. Also the Windows Explorer context menu has a *Cast to Device* option for supported file types. I am using an Arylic WiFi audio-only receiver. Somewhere in the menus of applications that can do this there is a "Cast to" option. Google Chrome can also cast, but probably only to a ChromeCast (it doesn't see my Arylic). I can't say whether it will also handle video - I don't see why not. I haven't yet been able to view video on a computer while casting the audio (I came here looking to solve that). Too late for the original poster, but I hope of use to someone.